# Incorrect Pluralizing of Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, migration

I looked around on Stack Overflow and Agile Development with Rails but couldn't find anything that answered all the parts of this I need.

I just generated a Cow model in rails. Apparently, Rails uses an antiquated plural of cow ("kine"), so when I created that model, it built a Kine migration:

```
class CreateKine < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :kine do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :farm
      t.string :breed

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I know I could go into the model's .rb file and set_table_name back to cow, but I'm worried about associated controllers. If I create a Cows controller, will it not sync up?

How do I get everything to be Cow/Cows?

This is one of my first apps, and I'm already way confused by managing controller-model associations, so this inflection issue doesn't help.

Comment: This rather arcane irregular inflection was [removed from Rails a few days ago](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c300dca9963bda78b8f358dbcb59cabcdc5e1dc9). Future versions will properly inflect `cow` as `cows`.

Comment: Good to hear. Though that's going to suck for everyone who wants to write a Rails 4 app to optimize 14th century Anglo-Saxon cattle herding.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Create an inflection here is an example:

config>initializers>inflections.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'cow', 'cows'
end
```

Comment: Great. And then just run rake db:migrate again?

Comment: Or should I roll back the model and then generate it again?

Comment: This is the right answer. @Sasha, just delete the migration and re-run the generator; it should generate `Cows` this time.

Comment: @Sasha just destroy what you generated with: rails destroy model Cow and then run the generator after adding the code mentioned in this answer

Answer (score 2):

Try to rename the table:

> ```
> class RenameKineToCows< ActiveRecord:Migration
>
>   def up
>     rename_table :kine, :cows
>   end 
>   def down
>     rename_table :cows, :kine
>   end
> end
> ```

Rename your app/models/kine.rb to cow.rb and edit the file

> ```
> class Cow < ActiveRecord::Base
>
>   self.table_name = 'Cow'
> end
> ```

Rename your app/controllers/kine_controller.rb to cows_controller.rb and edit the file

> ```
> class KineController < ApplicationController
> ```

to

> ```
> class CowsController < ApplicationController
> ```

and edit config/routes.rb

> ```
> resources :kine
> ```

to

> ```
> resources :cows
> ```

Comment: Thanks so much! Just double checking. In the migration you wrote up top, should self.up and self.down be the same? Or should self.down be "rename_table :cows, :kine"?